# nullify css property width and height for img (can't use "auto")

Tags: javascript, html, css

I build a plugin for websites (WP for example) and I need to nullify the css properties width and height for img elements in my plugin, to avoid effects of websites css (themes css).

I can't use "auto" because the behavior is a little bit diffrent. Browsers ignore the html attributes width and height in this case, but I need the element rendered in correct size while the image is still loading.

If I set css properties width and height explicitly via javascript - based on the values of html attributes - some browsers (FF & IE) ignore this during the loading process anyway (don't know why).

In this case the following code snippet:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.style.width = '100px';
img.style.height = '100px';
console.log(img.style.width);
console.log(img.offsetWidth);
```

outputs the following in FF and IE:

```
100px
0
```

Any ideas?

thanks,
Helmut

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the inline width and height declarations of an image?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the size attributes, or why it outputs what it does?

Comment: If the image or an ancestor has `display: none`, you'll get the behavior you're describing:  https://jsfiddle.net/t7mskqr2/

Comment: No, I don't want to remove any declarations or attributes. I only want to avoid effects from outside of my plugins div element. Within this div element there are images. And those img elements should be rendered in the size which is defined via html attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make a parent div for this image with width and height 100px and then set image width and height 100%.
This should work.